# How to stop voiceover reading letters as roman numerals in browser

Tags: web, voiceover

I have a client whose company name is essentially a roman numeral, i.e. IV, XI, XXC

Voiceover has decided that it should read these as numbers which makes is a hard listen.

**Is there a way to force voiceover to read suspected roman numerals as text in the browser?**

Only solution I can find is to add a span between the letters, add a space and give it a font-size of 0.1px a.k.a overly hacky.  There has to be a better way.